# How to send a logger as a null pointer exception

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

How can I send these loggers in the null pointer exception. How can I do the exception handling here? Also, how can I use a boolean variable like "status" to be printed at the end saying that an exception has been encountered in the code?

```
String strSchActStartTime = inData.getTransactionDetails().get("Schedule Actual Start Time");
if (strSchActStartTime == null) {
logger.debug("Schedule Actual Start Time is null "); //need to send this as an EXCEPTION in the response.
}
String strSchActEndTime = inData.getTransactionDetails().get("Schedule Actual End Time");
if (strSchActEndTime == null) {
logger.debug("Schedule Actual End Time is null "); //need to send this as an EXCEPTION in the response.
}
String breakStr = inData.getTransactionDetails().get("Break String");
String newValue = "\"EMPSKD_ACT_START_TIME" + slot + "=" + strSchActStartTime.trim() + "\"";
newValue = newValue + ",\"EMPSKD_ACT_END_TIME" + slot + "=" + strSchActEndTime.trim() + "\"";
if (breakStr != null) {
newValue = newValue + ",\"EMPSKD_BRKS=" + breakStr.trim() + "\"";
}
ovr.setOvrNewValue(newValue);
logger.debug("Schedule New Value : " + newValue);
oa.insert(ovr);
```

The second part of my code is as follows. Here, I am trying to do few things. I want to check if the ovrStartDate is before otlGoLiveDate and also before getPaygrpHandsOffDate. If yes, then go the successful code block, else throw an error. For that, I am using the boolean variable "Status". But I am not sure if I am doing it the right way.
Also, I am trying to see if the empId exists, if it is null then throw NPE. Here again the "status" can be used to return the exception.

```
Date otlGoLiveDate = AWAOTLHelper.getEmpGoLiveDate(ovr.getEmpId(), conn);           
logger.debug("otlGoLiveDate is: " + otlGoLiveDate.toString());  
if(otlGoLiveDate.after(ovr.getOvrStartDate())){
ovr.setOvrStatus(OverrideData.ERROR);
status = false;
ovr.setOvrMessage("Cannot enter overrides before go live date.");
}  
/*if((!ovr.getWbuName().equals("HR_REFRESH")) && otlGoLiveDate.after(ovr.getOvrStartDate())){
ovr.setOvrStatus(OverrideData.ERROR);               
ovr.setOvrMessage("Cannot enter overrides before go live date.");                   
}*/
EmployeeAccess ea = new EmployeeAccess(conn, CodeMapper.createCodeMapper(conn));
EmployeeData ed = ea.load(empId, ovrStartDate);
int payGrpId = ed.getPaygrpId();
PayGroupAccess pga = new PayGroupAccess(conn);
PayGroupData pgd = pga.load(payGrpId);
pgd.getPaygrpHandsOffDate();
logger.debug("PaygrpHandsOffDate : " +  pgd.getPaygrpHandsOffDate());  
if (ovrStartDate.before(pgd.getPaygrpHandsOffDate())) {
status = false;
ovr.setOvrMessage("Cannot enter overrides before Hands Off Date.");
}
```

Comment: "How to send a logger as a null pointer exception" - your question is unclear!

Comment: Worse than unclear: it's meangless. You can't 'send a logger as [or in] a null pointer exception'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use this type of method:

```
throw new NullPointerException("myMessage");
```

You can wrap all of your statements in a try catch block. That block should be able to catch any internally thrown exceptions.

```
try{
    String strSchActStartTime = inData.getTransactionDetails().get("Schedule Actual Start Time");
    if (strSchActStartTime == null) {
      //logger.debug("Schedule Actual Start Time is null "); //need to send this as an EXCEPTION in the response.
      throw new NullPointerException("Schedule Actual Start Time is null");
    }
    String strSchActEndTime = inData.getTransactionDetails().get("Schedule Actual End Time");
    if (strSchActEndTime == null) {
      logger.debug("Schedule Actual End Time is null "); //need to send this as an EXCEPTION in the response.
    }
    String breakStr = inData.getTransactionDetails().get("Break String");
    String newValue = "\"EMPSKD_ACT_START_TIME" + slot + "=" + strSchActStartTime.trim() + "\"";
    newValue = newValue + ",\"EMPSKD_ACT_END_TIME" + slot + "=" + strSchActEndTime.trim() + "\"";
    if (breakStr != null) {
      newValue = newValue + ",\"EMPSKD_BRKS=" + breakStr.trim() + "\"";
    }
    ovr.setOvrNewValue(newValue);
    logger.debug("Schedule New Value : " + newValue);
    oa.insert(ovr);
} catch (NullPointerException npe){
   //Code to handle the error
}
```

In regards to your second question. I see a few different ways to handle it.

In the following block, you could throw an exception:

```
if(otlGoLiveDate.after(ovr.getOvrStartDate())){
  ovr.setOvrStatus(OverrideData.ERROR);
  status = false;
  ovr.setOvrMessage("Cannot enter overrides before go live date.");
  throw new Exception("an error occurred");
}
```

Or at the end of everything you could put:

```
if(!status){
  throw new Exception("An error has occurred!");
}
```

You cannot pass a boolean value directly into an Exception constructor. Instead you have to get a string representation of that boolean value. String.valueOf(status).

Comment: Thank you. How can I check if the employee exists in the system and if he doesn't throw a NPE? I am also looking to use a boolean variable to return the status messages.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where you want to have the boolean variable added. When you use a try catch block, the program's execution will shift where the error is thrown. So if you encounter the first NPE, you will jump straight to the catch block. So there you could return a boolean variable to say that it encountered an error.

Comment: Got it. I added the second part of my code where I need the boolean variable to be used. Could you please check that and help me out. Thanks..

Comment: It looks like to me you want to read the the value of the boolean and if it is false throw an exception. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to check if empId exists,if not, throw an exception . That's the latter part of the question. In the first part, I am checking the condition which is ovrStartDate to be not before the otlGoLiveDate and getPaygrpHandsOffDate. If it is then throw an error using the boolean which should be false in that case.

Comment: If it's success can I just say the following?       if (status == true){
                 logger.debug(" Override status is successful ");                  
                }

Comment: Yes you can. There would be no reason to throw an exception.

Comment: No, I didn't want to throw an exception. But using the boolean is being done the right way, correct?

Comment: You can just write if(status) and it will evaluate to true if your boolean's value is true. Otherwise I would say yes you are using it as you intended.